# Parsing Single XML to pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing, tags

I have a single xml string as follows ( I show a sample here. It actually consists of 10K+ such elements, but all elements are included in the myData Tag)

myxml =

```
        <myData>
     <x1="A" name="P1" supp="TU01" type="CA"  date="200607" proc="Y" iden="1" />
     <x1="B" name="Q1" supp="TU01" type="CA" date="200609" proc="N"  iden="5" />
     <x1="B" name="R1" supp="UY7" type="CA"  date="200609" proc="N" iden="12"  />
      </myData>
```

My goal is to parse this xml string and get it into a tabular pandas dataframe like structure with columns like x1, name, supp, type, date, proc & iden.

So my dataframe (output)  should look like

```
  df = 

       x1 name supp type date    proc  iden
    
       A   P1  TU01  CA  200607   Y     1
       B   Q1  TU01  CA  200609   N     5
       B   R1  UY7   CA  200609   N     12
```

As a first step I was trying to the following , but its not working as I am not getting anything apart from the x1 from 3 elements:

```
         from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

         root = ET.fromstring(myxml)

         print(root)

         for child in root.iter('*'):

              print(child.tag)
```

This one itself does not give me what I expect. Later I wanted to create a dict from which I was thinking to create the pandas dataframe:

```
          xmlDict = {}
          for parent in root:

            child = parent.getchildren()

            xmlDict[child[0].text] = child[1].text
```

Any help in these regards will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that your original XML is not well formed.
Each tag should contain a **tag name**, whereas descendants of *myData* have
**only attributes**.

Use the following XML with some tag name, e.g. *row*:

```
<myData>
     <row x1="A" name="P1" supp="TU01" type="CA" date="200607" proc="Y" iden="1" />
     <row x1="B" name="Q1" supp="TU01" type="CA" date="200609" proc="N" iden="5" />
     <row x1="B" name="R1" supp="UY7"  type="CA" date="200609" proc="N" iden="12" />
</myData>
```

Then read the source string as in your code:

```
root = ET.fromstring(myxml)
```

And to create the DataFrame, run:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ child.attrib for child in root.iter('row') ])
```

The result is:

```
  x1 name  supp type    date proc iden
0  A   P1  TU01   CA  200607    Y    1
1  B   Q1  TU01   CA  200609    N    5
2  B   R1   UY7   CA  200609    N   12
```

(the leftmost column is the index).

**Update:**

If you have *pandas* in version 1.3.0 or later, you can do without *ElementTree*.
Just call:

```
df = pd.read_xml(myxml)
```